# Rails two objects in one json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have tree models: Tours, buses and locations
Tour have more buses, buses more locations.

I want to return json object with buses last locations for some tour.

Pseudo example:

```
  BUSES

    BUS1
      last_location
    /BUS1

    BUS2
      last_location
    /BUS2

    BUS3
      last_locaiton
    /BUS3

  /BUSES
```

tour.buses will give me buses for that tour, and bus.locations.last latest location.

I know that is no since fiction, but I don't know how to pack this in one json object to return it :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
both_pieces = {
    :tour          => tour,
    :last_location => bus.locations.last
}
```

And then send `both_pieces` back as JSON. Then the client would get one JSON object with the `tour` and `last_location` objects inside it.